# How to remove Paste Options from the right click (context) menu in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, context-menu

Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.  Windows 8.1

To remove "paste options" from right click menu in Outlook, I've already made the de-selection in the File Options Mail Editor Options Advanced back stage list (deselected "Show Paste Options button when content is pasted), but all of the Paste options still show up on the right click when my cursor is in the body of a Reply or New Email.
So... is there another selection or deselection I need to make? Or can you provide me with instructions on how to edit / remove paste options from the right click (context) menu in Outlook?
Thank you.

Comment: I got the same result, it is not possible to disable those controls.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same results with you; it is not possible to disable those controls.
See this [link](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?PAGEN_1=2&FID=5&TID=9679#nav_start:%7E:text=It%20is%20not%20possible%20to%20disable%20those%20controls.)

Comment: Do you think my reply is helpful? If so, please accept it as answer to help other people.